# SQL Server : delete duplicates where 4 columns match but keep those that have a particular value in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, logic, sql-delete

I have an approvals system, columns are `name, manager, traveldate, purpose, approved`. I need to find and remove all but one duplicate if the name, manager, traveldate and purpose are the same as another record on the table, without deleting any that may have been approved already

e.g. when 3 have a matching name, manager, traveldate and purpose and are not approved 2 should be deleted but when 4 have a matching name, manager, traveldate and purpose but 2 are approved, then only the 2 unapproved should be deleted

Comment: Tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. All as formatted text, not images.

Comment: Do you have a column that can be used to uniquely identify a record (or at least a record within groups of records havin the same `(name, manager, traveldate, purpose)`?

Comment: @GMB there is an ID field

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
with cte as (
      select sum(case when approved <> 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by name, manager, traveldate, purpose) as cnt_approved,
             row_number() over over (partition by name, manager, traveldate, purpose, approved order by approved
                                    ) as seqnum
             t.*
      from mytable t
     )
delete from cte
    where approved = 0 and
          ((cnt_approved > 0  or
           (cnt_approved = 0 and seqnum > 1)
          );
```

Answer (score 0):

For this to be solvable in a consistent manner, it would be good to have a column that can be used to disambiguate (sort) the records that have the same `(name, manager, traveldate, purpose)`. Assuming that such a column exists and is called `id`, you could proceed as follows:

```
with cte as (
    select row_number() 
        over(partition by name, manager, traveldate, purpose order by id) rn
    from mytable
    where approved = 0
)
delete from cte where rn > 1
```

This will delete the records that have the same `(name, manager, traveldate, purpose)` and that have `approved = 0`, while retaining the record with the smallest `id`.

If you don't have such a column, then you are left with keeping a random record per group, by using `newid()` for ordering:

```
with cte as (
    select row_number() 
        over(partition by name, manager, traveldate, purpose order by newid()) rn
    from mytable
    where approved = 0
)
delete from cte where rn > 1
```

Comment: sorry, it has ID,  i didnt mention it as its second nature adding one for me